# rsInvalidAggregateScope error in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling, textbox, aggregate-functions, time-and-attendance

```
Dataset: 

    select col1, col2, col3, Possible_Duration, Present_Duration
    from table
```

I am designing a report which shows student data and calculating attendance as `SUM(Present duration)/SUM(Possible duration)` in an expression.

Detail text box: uses attendance field from dataset

Properties-> FontFamily: =First(Fields!Table_Total_Font_Family.Value, "Styles")

But I am getting this error on execution

> The FontFamily expression for the textbox ‘Textbox21' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a data set.

I even tried taking the SUM fields from dataset but cannot eliminate the error.

Any idea where am I going wrong.

Comment: What is the precise expression you are using?  In what tablixes/matrixes? There's not enough information here to advise.

Comment: @Jonnus I am using SUM(Present duration)/SUM(Possible duration) and FontFamily: =First(Fields!Table_Total_Font_Family.Value, "Styles")

Comment: Will what are "present duration" and "possible duration"? These don't appear to be fields in a dataset (I.e. Fields!present_duration.value) so how are they being summed?

Comment: dataset: select col1, col2, col3, Possible_Duration,Present_Duration
from table

Comment: What is the ***precise expression*** you are using?  In what ***tablixes/matrixes***? There's not enough information here to advise.

Comment: I am just using above dataset in table and calculating Sum(Present duration) and Sum(Possible Duration) i.e Add totals for Present and Possible duration and combining First and Last names for Name field. Thant's it I am not sure why I keep getting this FontFamily expression message :(

Comment: What is "styles"? Is this another dataset?

Comment: Yes, someone created this report and there is ReportStyles dataset where fonts, borders, colours are being set

Comment: Well if the dataset is called "reportstyles" this is what should be in the expression, not "styles"

Comment: Thanks for that Jonnus..I will try tomorrow morning and will let you know if that works!